# Flutter multi-platform Android / iOS drawer menu

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How does one implement a menu widget on iOS equivalent to the Android (Material) drawer in Flutter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no straightforward alternative menu widget in iOS, because [Apple doesn't recommend drawers at all](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/drawers/).

> A drawer is a type of interface element that contains options or information 
>   related to a specific window. A drawer is hidden by default, and can
>   only be revealed when the parent window is visible on screen. When
>   revealed, typically in response to a button, menu, or action, the
>   drawer slides out from one of side of the parent window. A drawer
>   can’t be moved separately or detached from its parent window.
>
> Avoid using drawers. Drawers are seldom used in modern apps and their
>   use is discouraged. Panels, popovers, sidebars, and split views are
>   preferred for displaying supplementary window content.

**Quick solution**

[image]

**Example**

The Flutter team has prepared a [comprehensive example of Android / iOS multiplatform app design](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/platform_design).

[image: image description]

Comment: The linked example is opensource, but some code excerpts may be useful here within the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this yourself. You can use `Positioned` and `GestureDetector`, for example. Than you can animate it's moving. Is done very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you can workaround by defining a page that you use in the drawer for Android and as just another page for iOS:

```
Widget settingsWheel = Platform.isAndroid
        ? Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => IconButton(
            icon: settingsIcon,
            onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
            tooltip: "Open App Settings",
          ))
        : Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoButton(
            child: settingsIcon,
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppSettings.pageRoute),
          ));
```

...and then give it a "drawer-ish" feel by sliding the page in from the left:

```
onGenerateRoute: (route){
          if (route.name == AppSettings.pageRoute) {
            return PageTransition(
              child: AppSettings(),
              type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight,
              settings: route,);
          }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply place the `Drawer` in the `endDrawer` attribute of `Scaffold`, example:

```
Drawer(
              child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: myColour,
                    ),
                    accountName:
                    Padding(child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Marcelo Augusto Elias"),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: whiteColour,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ), padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),),                     

                    accountEmail: Text("N° Cartão: XXXX XXXX XXXX 5154"),
                    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor:
                          Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                              ? myColour
                              : Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Fatura"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_fatura_barra_menu.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Fatura()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ConsultaMargem()),
                      );
                    },
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Extrato"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_barra_menu_extrato.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DesbloquearPrimeiraVia()),
                      );
                    },
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Desbloquear Cartão"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_barra_menu_desbloquearcartao.png",
                      width: 24.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Meu Cartão"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_barra_menu_meucartao.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Contracheques()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => HistoricoConsignacoes()),
                      );
                    },
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Adiantamento Salarial"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_barra_menu_adiantamentosalarial.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  /* ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ConsultaMargem()),
                      );
                    },
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Consulta de Margem"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_consulta_margem.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ), */
                  /* ListTile(
              dense: true,
              title: Text("Informe de Rendimentos"),
              leading: new Image.asset(
                "assets/images/icon_rendimento.png",
                width: 20.0,
              ),
            ), */
                  /* ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SimularEmprestimos()),
                      );
                    },
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Simular Empréstimo"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/Icon_cal.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ), */
                  Divider(),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Compartilhar"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_compartilhar.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Avaliar"),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_estrela.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(),
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text("Sair"),
                    trailing: Text(
                      "Versão 2.0",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    leading: new Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/icon_porta_sair.png",
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Comment: And where's the iOS alternative?

Comment: Btw, ListView actually doesn't seem to currently work on iOS at all.